# Validation Error while adding kendo dropdownlinst in kendo grid cell

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

[image]

Kendo Dropdownlist added successfully in kendo grid but when clicked on dropdownlist it shows the error as shown in image (browser console). 
Here below is the javascript code used for kendo grid. I took help from http://jsbin.com/vefarikadu/edit?html,js,output but couldn't correct it. So anyone know what's going on here?

```
var url = webApiUri + "/Finance/";
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: url + "GetBillItemList",
                data: { BillId: $('#BillId').val() },
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
                }
            },
            create: {
                dataType: "json"
            },
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 5,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "BillId",
                fields: {
                    BillItemId: { editable: false, nullable: true,hidden:true },
                    OfficeId: { field: "OfficeId",defaultValue: 1 },
                    ItemBill: { type: "integer", validation: { required: true },title:"@Mars.CultureResource.Entity.CultureResourceEntity.ItemBill" },
                    ItemNote: { type: "string", validation: { required: true }, title:"@Mars.CultureResource.Entity.CultureResourceEntity.ItemNote" },
                }
            }
        },
        aggregate:[
                    { field:"ItemBill", aggregate:"sum" }
        ],
    });

    $("#BillItemGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        navigatable: true,
        pageable: true,
        editable: "incell",
        toolbar: ["create"],
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "BillItemId", title:"Bill Item Id", hidden:true},
            { field: "OfficeId", width: "150px", editor: categoryDropDownEditor,title: "Office",template: "#=getCategoryName(OfficeId)#"},
            { field: "ItemNote", title: "@Mars.CultureResource.Entity.CultureResourceEntity.ItemNote",footerTemplate:"Sum" },
            { field: "ItemBill", title: "@Mars.CultureResource.Entity.CultureResourceEntity.ItemBill",footerTemplate:"<span id='totalitembillfooter'> #= sum #</span> "  },
            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 150 }],
        editable: true,
        edit: function(e) {
            var input = e.container.find(".k-input");
            $("[name='ItemBill']", e.container).blur(function(){
                onbillamountchange();
                $("#totalitembillfooter").html(calc());
            });

        },

    });

});

function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="OfficeName" data-value-field="OfficeId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource:OfficeListArray
        });
}

function getCategoryName(OfficeId) {
    for (var idx = 0, length = OfficeListArray.length; idx < length; idx++) {
        if (OfficeListArray[idx].OfficeId === OfficeId) {
            return OfficeListArray[idx].OfficeName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate "it shows the error as shown in image console" , i haven't notice any error from jsfiddle console

Comment: @machun  Sorry about earlier, I forgot to attach error image. But I have attached it now. The image shows the error in my project.

Comment: what is  `data-valmsg-for` ? shouldn't it be `data-msg-for` ?

Comment: Thanx machun I finally found it in kendo.aspnetmvc.js , I replaced data-valmsg-for with data-msg-for and it worked but I'm afraid whether repalcing it would create any other trouble or not. Anyways thanx for time

Comment: i dont think it will create trouble, haven't read any data-valmsg-for script, btw can i posted it as the answer , so it can be helpful for other too?

Comment: Yes u can! Also I found out that I've been using 2013 release kendo js so I replace it with 2015 release and it solved the issue

Comment: Using kendo 2015 can you use the `data-valmsg-for`? if yes better you post the answer because you actually fix it alone, and summary this conversation :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it! I was using kendo.aspnetmvc.js from 2013 release, later I replaced it with 2015 release and it solved the issue. No need to replace **data-valmsg-for**. But if you want to use 2013 release itself then replace **data-valmsg-for** with **data-msg-for** as told by @muchan. It worked too!